# Add buffering to real time input stream with c++ ffmpeg

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, buffering

I am writing a c++ program in which I am handling a real time udp video stream with the ffmpeg library.

The video input fps is 25 frames per second in avarage. The gap between two frames can be 10 , 20, 40 milliseconds, but sometimes it can be around 80 milliseconds.
In those times, when the gap is around 80 milliseconds, the video seems choppy  or stuck,

When I open the same stream with the ffplay player(using the ffplay.exe), using a simple 
"ffplay.exe udp://ip:port" command, the video has a little delay (around 50 millisends) with respect to the origin stream, but it runs much more smoothly.

Can I set a buffering time or any minimal delay so that the delay between the frames will be much more steady, in my c++ program?
If so, how can I do this?

Thanks,
Joel

Comment: That seems to be answered in question itself. IOW yes, ffplay does it. What are you asking?

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: Answer is still same that yes, there is a program https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/fftools/ffplay.c that does it, therefore it is possible in your program too.

Comment: I edited my question again. I have tried to find the solution to my problem but didn't find that, that's why I am asking for help.

Comment: You describe that you receive frames at unsteady rate in 10 to 80 milliseconds but that is bad, you want to present those at steady rate like after every 40 milliseconds. Is it possible? Yes. How? By implementing it. Even example code is available. I have absolutely no idea with what you are stuck there. What did you try? Why it did not work?

Comment: What I am looking for is an option, filter or anything like that in the ffmpeg c++ protocol that whould do this for me. For example, I can run a command through the ffmpeg cmd line like "ffplay udp://ip:port -fflags nobuffer -flags low_delay" and there will be an influence on the input stream. I am looking for something similar, but in my c++ program, like using the c++ ffmpeg api and get some buffering time or any other solution

Comment: Then you are likely looking for something that does not exist. The ffmpeg is written in C and does not have official "C++ fmpeg API". http://ffmpeg.org/ Also it  does not have anything what such task would normally take (like frame queues, ring-buffers, and synchronizing between decoding and presenting threads).  What your undisclosed C++ API uses for that (like pthread, std::thread, QThread or SDL_Thread)? The ffplay clearly implements it all itself using SDL_Thread.

Comment: Thanks for your answers!